# Redirect to a specific search result

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, redirect

I have a scraper to pull search results from a number of travel websites. Now that I have the search results nicely displayed with "Book Now" buttons, I want those "Book Now" buttons to redirect to the specific search result so the user can book that specific travel search result. These search results are dynamic so the redirect may change.

What's the easiest way to accomplish this? I'm building this search engine in Python/Django and have Django CMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you storing the results in a database or some persistent storage mechanism (maybe even in a KV store)?

Once you hold the results somewhere on your website, you can redirect from your results page via the Book Now button to a view withs the result's identifying value (say some hash) and have that view redirect to the website offering the service.

Comment: Yes, the results are stored in a DB. Okay, so basically, I should be pulling the final booking page links along with all of the other data, and then store it to use for the book now button?

Comment: Exactly. From your results page, you won't go directly to the other website but you want that link. Instead, you'll want to route through your own view so that you can capture the click and do any other kind of pre-redirect processing.

Comment: @JBear, if my answer is good, please mark it as the solution. Thanks. :)

Comment: I didn't actually get it working yet - I'm dealing with a bunch of webscrape/ux issues atm. I'll mark it as correct by logic and if I have any issues with it, I'll come back to the thread and ping you if that's okay :)